# Get all characters to the left of a specific character in further increasing depth

Tags: vb.net

I have the following string:

```
folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4
```

I need to cut the string at each slash, so I end up with:

```
folder
folder1\folder2
folder1\folder2\folder3
folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4
```

I tried using substring and `Split("\"c)(0)` and that gives me `folder` but how I do now get `folder1\folder2`, etc.?

Comment: Where is `folder` coming from? Do you mean `folder1`? -- When you split on `"\"`, you get back an array with all the parts, you just need to loop the collection a reassemble it.

Comment: Don't treat file and folder paths like regular `Strings`. Use the `Path` class to manipulate them. Pass the full path to `Path.GetDirectoryName` and you'll get the path one level up. You can then pass that and get the next level up and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I have a string being read from a file which contains folder paths. The string could read "folder1\folder2" or it could be many folders deep. I want to be able to split the string at any folder depth I want. Say the string is like this: folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4 and I want to split it to the 3rd folder level and only read folder1\folder2\folder3

Comment: @amaru96 If you have `Dim likeThis = "folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4"` and `Dim parts = likeThis.Split("\"c)`, then `Dim first3 = String.Join("\", parts.Take(3))` will give "folder1\folder2\folder3`.

Comment: Or something like: `dim parts = new Uri(Path.Combine("\\path", "folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4"))`. Now , in `path.Segments` you have the parts already separated, just loop from 1 to `path.Segments.Length` and build a string with segments 1-n.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Morton, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I took @Andrew Morton's comment and add the `For` loop to get the results you pictured. The `For` loop will work for any length path.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s = "folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4"
    Dim folders = s.Split("\"c)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For i = 0 To folders.Length - 1
        sb.AppendLine(String.Join("\", folders.Take(i + 1)))
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

Result displayed in TextBox1:

```
folder1
folder1\folder2
folder1\folder2\folder3
folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4
```

Comment: Thanks Mary but I don't need all the folder paths. I only need 1 path, of which I specify the depth. For example, I want to get to the 3rd folder level, so the result should be folder1\folder2\folder3. The next time I might need to get the 2nd folder level, so the result should be folder1\folder2.